# Configuration logging in Play Framework at start up auto-test

Tags: java, log4j, playframework

I configured the logging in my Play Framework application. When I run application in prod or dev mode or run test by comand (play test) - everything works fine, but test can not executes when I run their 'play auto-test'. Please help!

in application.conf:

```
application.log=INFO
application.log.path=/log4j.xml
```

log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="${application.path}/logs/application.log"/>
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB"/>
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m %n"/>
      </layout>
  </appender>
 <logger name="play">
     <level value="error"/>
 </logger>
 <root>
     <priority value="error"/>
     <appender-ref ref="file"/>
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

When I use the   following log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
      </layout>
  </appender>
 <logger name="play">
     <level value="debug"/>
 </logger>
 <root>
     <priority value="info"/>
     <appender-ref ref="console"/>
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

tests running the command 'play auto-test'  successfully executed. Please tell how configure logging in Play (output to file) that run and executes tests in 'play auto-test'!

Answer (score 1):

Thi is pretty much a Play! bug. It's not caused by the fact that you've configured log4j with a separate file, though doing that will hide another error message: "play.tmp is null when it should be play.tmp=none" (something to this liking - you'll get this if you remove your custon log4j.xml file and re-do "play auto-test"). Problem is that even if you set that to play.tmp=none it will still not work. Besides, if you compare their online documentation to Play!'s console output you'll already realize that something's wrong:

The docs say:

"The 'auto-test' command do the same than the 'test' command, but it automatically launch a browser, run all the tests, and stop."

Console sais (when you do "play auto-test"):

```
ATTENTION: You're running Play! in DEV mode
~
~ Go to http://localhost:9000/@tests to run the tests
~
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was very simple

in application.conf:

```
%test.application.log=INFO
%test.application.log.path=/log4j.xml

application.log=INFO
application.log.path=/log4j.properties
application.log.system.out=off
```

log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
      </layout>
  </appender>
 <logger name="play">
     <level value="debug"/>
 </logger>
 <root>
     <priority value="info"/>
     <appender-ref ref="console"/>
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, Rolling
log4j.logger.play=INFO
log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=${application.path}/logs/application.log
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m %n
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, welcome to stackoverflow. It's not wrong to answer your own questions, especially if you think someone benefits from them. Could you however quickly sum up what you did? We're just mere mortals and don't read XML as our base language. Did you have two Apache config files, one in XML and one in property format and the wrong one got selected?